# Hide Icon but keep Running Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hide

i an completely new in Android Studio.
now i am working on hide and unhide my app with this code,

```
public void HideApps (Context context){
    PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class);
    // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as
    // <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void unhideApps (Context context){
    PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Void UnhideApps will working when i call with something like #007. i have completed to do that. But now i want this app keep running although this app is hide. because i create some function like record audio. if record is on and i hide this app i need record not stopped.

kindly someone give me advice to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have succeed use extend services and windowManager. 
Thanks..